# get_key_if_pressed proc is not working-Assembly

Tags: assembly

I tried to make a function that when someone clicks the "+" button, it will do something.
I used interrupt 16 (ah 01h).

But it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
   proc get_key_if_pressed
mov ax, 0
int 16h
mov ax, 0
mov ah, 01h
int 16h
@@done:
ret
endp get_key_if_pressed

proc toolbarCheck
call get_key_if_pressed
cmp ax, 0
je @@done

cmp al, 43
je @@sizeUp

jmp @@done

@@sizeUp:
add [sizeDraw] , 1

@@done:
ret
endp toolbarCheck
```

Thank You!

Comment: [Int 16/AH=01h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm) doesn't wait for a keystroke, it only checks if one is available at the time of the call. It is usually used in a loop. Maybe you wanted [Int 16/AH=00h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm)?

Comment: @MargaretBloom I tried. This is not working.

Comment: Can you post the updated code? The Zero Flag test actually in place should be removed too.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I updated the code.